# How do I url-encode in Dart in the format that the Twitter API expects?

Tags: encoding, dart, uriencoding

I [wrote some code](https://blog.dantup.com/2016/07/simplest-csharp-code-to-post-a-tweet-using-oauth/) to post tweets in C#. One of the things that tripped me up was the url-encoding of data since there seemed to be many options:

```
var input = "Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!";
var expected = "Hello%20Ladies%20%2B%20Gentlemen%2C%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request%21";

Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.UrlEncode(input) == expected); // False
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeUriString(input) == expected); // False
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeDataString(input) == expected); // True
```

I'm now trying to do the same thing in Dart. I've tried all the encode methods in the Uri class, but none seem to output the same.

Code: ([DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a8874dae0de40be353dace32512becfc))

```
print(Uri.encodeQueryComponent("Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!"));
print(Uri.encodeFull("Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!"));
print(Uri.encodeComponent("Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!"));
```

Output:

```
Hello+Ladies+%2B+Gentlemen%2C+a+signed+OAuth+request%21
Hello%20Ladies%20+%20Gentlemen,%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request!
Hello%20Ladies%20%2B%20Gentlemen%2C%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request!
```

The last one (`encodeComponent`) seems the closest, just the exclamation mark is wrong.

Is there an existing method that does this encoding as I require (the same as C#'s `EscapeDataString`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [convert package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/convert) works perfectly. There was previously a bug causing numbers to be encoded but [a fix was merged](https://github.com/dart-lang/convert/pull/4) and released today in 2.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

I can't find a Dart function that is equivalent to C#'s `EscapeDataString`, however I think I was able to implement one. Feel free to try it and see if you find any issues.

See this Dartpad: 
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4336dad4dc0603952a7c2e545cb8726c

It's based on the fact that the Dart docs says:

`All characters except uppercase and lowercase letters, digits and the characters -_.!~*'() are percent-encoded.`

So the functions I provided adds percent encoding of those specific characters.

As I understand it from the C# docs on `EscapeDataString` it does encode these characters by default whereas no Dart function I could find does that.

Comment: Thanks; though I'm really surprised there's no built-in version. Someone pointed me at the convert package, which is closer, except it fails on numbers! https://github.com/dart-lang/convert/issues/3